# Kinesis Advantage F7 and F8 acts as email and internet buttons

Tags: keyboard, media-keys

Pressing the F7 key on my [Kinesis Advantage](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/advantage-for-pc-mac/) causes Outlook to start up and pressing the F8 key causes Chrome, my default browser, to start.  I tried using a few key code listeners to see what codes they are sending, but they didn't detect anything when I pressed F7 and F8.  I'm guessing that they send `VK_BROWSER_HOME 0xAC` and `VK_LAUNCH_MAIL 0xB4`.

I don't need an email or internet key on my keyboard and I want to be able to use the F7 and F8 keys. I have tried using the keyboard's Remap function to reset the two keys to F7 and F8 by entering remap mode and pressing F7 twice, then F8 twice, but that has not worked.

I would like to know what is causing these keys to behave in this way and what I can do to fix the problem.

**Edit:** I have gotten these results on two different computers running Windows 7 and the F7 and F8 keys on a regular acer keyboard work fine on these computers.

**Edit2:** I've tried using SharpKeys to remap the keys, but unfortunately it doesn't recognize them:

When I go to add a mapping in SharpKeys and use `Type Key`, both F7 and F8 open my browser instead of F7 opening Outlook.  The key code it displays alternates randomly between E0_4000 and 00_100 for both F7 and F8 and when I press `OK` it shows a message box saying:

> You've entered a key that SharpKeys doesn't know about.
>
> Please check the SharpKeys website for an updated release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insertsnideremarks at the Mechanical Keyboards subreddit found a [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/520duv/help_kinesis_advantage_f7_and_f8_acts_as_email/d7gvo7f) on pages 40-42 of the [user's manual](http://kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/advantage-usb-manual.pdf).

> To turn off settings individually, hold = and tap the appropriate key (=F7, =F8). To turn of both settings at
>   once in this group, activate one of the master settings (=m, =p, or =w).

Comment: I am on windows so I was able to hold = and tap w (for windows,m for mac) to get things back to normal. Thank you!